# Visualize files and directories

Tags: macos, visualization

Is there an application (ideally for Mac) that would allow you to visualize / display graphically all the files and sub-directories within a directory?

Answer (score 4):

I use a program called [Disk Inventory X](http://www.derlien.com/).  It has served me well for quite a while.  And it's free :)

[image: http://www.derlien.com/assets/main.jpg]
http://www.derlien.com/assets/main.jpg

Comment: This program appears to be a remake of KDirStat from Linux, not that that's a bad thing.  That does lend credence to its awesomeness, however.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind working from the command line, the `tree` command does what you want. It's more or less standard on Linux and comes with Windows. I gather it's not installed by default on the Mac, but it's [easy to obtain](http://shaunchapman.me/post/329270449/how-to-install-the-tree-command-on-mac-os-x).

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Josh's answer but for Windows, [SequoiaView](http://w3.win.tue.nl/nl/onderzoek/onderzoek_informatica/visualization/sequoiaview//) is a free tool that does a squarified treemap visualization of your directory structure.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

GrandPerspectiv works on OSX and is updated as of December 2018. It's also free and open source! Wonderful!

[image: GrandPerspectiv]