# How to see whats taking up space on your hard drive

Tags: macos, mac, hard-drive, ssd, disk-space

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Visualize files and directories](https://superuser.com/questions/471201/visualize-files-and-directories)

Im thinking of switching to one of the macbook pro retinas with a 256gb ssd, im making the move from a 512gb hd, which at the moment is split into a 60bg windows partition (which i dont think im going to have on my new machine) and a 440gb main partition of the main partition ive got 140gb free.

So all in if i disregard the 60gb windows part ive got about 200gb free so im using 300gb, which is still a bit to much, ive had this machine 4/5 yrs so its likely to be clogged with files that i no longer need, is there a tool that i can use to view my current hd and see whats taking up the most room, so i can begin to see where i can cut down ?

just for a bit of background my current machine runs osx.

Answer (score 3):

I use jDiskReport

"JDiskReport enables you to understand how much space the files and directories consume on your disk drives, and it helps you find obsolete files and folders."

It draws a nice pie-chart that lets you identify quikly the biggest folders.

The tool is available for Windows, Mac OS S and Linux, and it's free.

http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/jdiskreport/

Answer (score 2):

You can use the command line too `du` to power your way through folders.

> DU(1)                     BSD General Commands Manual
>
> NAME
>        du -- display disk usage statistics
>
> SYNOPSIS
>        du [-H | -L | -P] [-a | -s | -d depth] [-c] [-h | -k | -m | -g] [-x] [-I mask] [file ...]
>
> DESCRIPTION
>        The du utility displays the file system block usage for each file argument and for each directory in
>        the file hierarchy rooted in each directory argument.  If no file is specified, the block usage of the
>        hierarchy rooted in the current directory is displayed.

You can also use a GUI tool like [Disk Inventory X](http://www.derlien.com/) to visualize your disk usage.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the FileLight version for Mac here: http://freecode.com/projects/macfilelight

theres also:
http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/33170/diskring

http://maketecheasier.com/another-great-disk-usage-analyzer-for-the-masses/2009/02/22